# White space left after a line break

Tags: html, css, text

Is there any way to get rid of that white space after a line break?
If you highlight the text node only it actually requires less space that paragraph is trying to take.

```css
.wrap {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  max-width: 470px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <p>
    We weren't able to change your trading or correspondence address. Please try again or come back later.
  </p>
</div>
```

Example:
https://codepen.io/patryk-ptak/pen/yLGZjqE

@EDIT:
I mean this additional red space added after the line break.

[image]

I need that `max-width` property so removing it is not an option for me.

@EDIT2:
Important - the text is dynamic so I have no control over it, it has to be rendered in a singular `p` tag and I cannot shove any tags in between words :)
I can only control parent node, I hoped there are some CSS `edge-cases` for this that can be somehow addressed but it seems like it's not the case.

Additionally, I'm getting info that this post is being closed because it was already answered somewhere else and it's pointing me to a completely different post... Stackoverflow is such a pain...

Comment: what `white space` or `line break`? I didn't detect any problems in HTML rendering

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by "get rid of that white space after a line break?"  you don't have any line breaks here - unless you are talking about the wrap red background which is an entirely different thing.  Are you saying you do not wish to have the extra space that the paragraph element puts in place by default?

Comment: If i understand correctly, you want to play with the [`line-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height). You want to use `line-height:1`, but keep in mind that using 1 can cause problems to people with accessibility issues.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss please see edited post :)

Comment: With the additional clarification I have voted to Reopen as I tend to agree with your assessment here.  Just to be clear I originally voted to close for clarity but the update addresses that for me here. @Ptak  You can also vote to Reopen I believe.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss OP needs 125 rep. to cast a reopen vote on their own Qs.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss sadly it's not me ;) ^

Comment: Find the "Take the tour" and fill your profile out to get a bit of rep.  other quick startup suggestions: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252149/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-stack-overflow also review https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261079/how-can-i-get-initial-reputation-on-stack-overflow

Comment: You have a misconception about the method of calculating Div width.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="wrap">
  <p>
    We weren't able to change your trading or correspondence address.
  </p>
  <br/>
   <p>
     Please try again or come back later.
  </p>
</div>
```

A combination of separating the elements into different paragraph tags, placing a line break in between, and changing the style to have an inline display will get rid of the extra space after the sentences.
If you add a class to the paragraph elements, use that class to target the sentences, if not, you can use this updated CSS/selector:

```
.wrap > * {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  max-width: 470px;
  display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your desire you can alter from the default for a `p` element CSS which is:

```css
display:block;
unicode-bidi: embed;
margin: 1.12em 0;
```

and make this `inline` then adjust the line height to get rid of the white line between the "lines" And then move the background to that element.

NOTE: I added borders JUST to show what is where.  These are not part of the solution and are only to illustrate this example.

```css
body {
  border: solid green 1px;
}

.wrap {
  color: white;
  max-width: 470px;
  font-size: 0;
  border: solid blue 1px;
}

p {
  background: red;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <p>We weren't able to change your trading or correspondence address. Please try again or come back later.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this what you had as a desired result here? i.e. can you put CSS on that child paragraph like this, and is that your desired result?

Answer (score -2):

```css
.wrap {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  max-width: 470px;
  width: fit-content; 
}

/* this css for another way */
.wrap p span {
display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <p>
    We weren't able to change your trading or correspondence address. <br> Please try again or come back later.
  </p>
</div>


<div class="wrap">
  <p>
   <span>  We weren't able to change your trading or correspondence address. </span>          <span> Please try again or come back later.</span>   
  </p>
</div>
```

@edit: if remove extra background color so add in wrap `width: fit-content;`

Comment: I can't remove `max-width` as this is part of the element (this is within the toast)

Comment: if you able to edit in so add `span` tag in requirement of line break and add css of this span  `display: block;`

Comment: the thing is that this text is dynamic, I was just wondering if there's a way to prevent this weird behaviour w/o any structural changes.

Comment: if remove extra background color so add in wrap `width: fit-content;`

Comment: This is still structural change, I want the whole text to be in the single `p` tag w/o any explicit `br`s :)